# wso2 bps human task can I set deadline for a task to be completed

Tags: wso2

As I look at samples of human task deadline sample, it sets deadline for when owners should start a task. 
After a task is created with deadline, system will create a timer based on task created time plus the deadline delta.

In my situation, I need to set deadline when this task should be completed. It is an absolute time. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try Sample [1]. If sample doesn't fit your scenario, Look at the deadline syntax [2] change according to that. You should be able to this..

[1] http://tryitnw.blogspot.com/2013/05/escalating-human-task-with-wso2-bps.html

[2] http://docs.oasis-open.org/bpel4people/ws-humantask-1.1-spec-cs-01.html#_Toc135718795

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will disappoint you, but had a requirement also that a task that was not picked up, ended automatically after a set time. Link (2) mentions the way to define this in the task, but the handling of this is not implemented in BPS (I use this regularly in Oracle SOA).

I ended up defining the timeout in the payload, and created an event listener that used quartz to track the task timeout. The quartz job then ends the task as needed. This should be a feature request in WSO2 though.

Comment: Got it, I looked at the human task client wsdl, there is  method setTaskCompletionDeadlineExpression, but it is not implemented. Also the expression is a string.